# Is there a function that automatically moves my cursor in R to the error found in my code?

Tags: r, performance

Whenever I get an error in my code, I have to start looking on which line it is. Having only 500 lines or so, this is doable, but I can imagine the efficiency boost I would get if there'd be a keyboard shortcut that automatically moves my cursor to the error.

Anyone that found such a shortcut?
I am working in R script.

Comment: Could you give more details?  It's not exactly clear what you want to do.  Are you using RStudio?  Do you want to jump to the error when it occurs, or later, based on the error message?

Comment: I do not mean any code, just shortcuts. If you press SHIFT + ALT + K, it opens the cheat sheet, but there's no shortcut to jump to errors.

What I mean with 'jumping to errors': you have your cursor on line 1, you run your code, and there's an error on line 500. Instead of R moving your cursor automatically to that line, you have to do it manually. I hate using my mouse for this, and jumping to the bottom of the code only to then go up is also cumbersome. I ideally look for a shortcut like: control + shift + E that would move my cursor automatically. However, this is non-existent.

Answer (score 3):

You could set `error` option to `browser` or `recover` (as suggested by @Ben Bolker).

With `browser`:

```
options(error=browser)


test <- function() {
  1+1
  stop('custom error')
}

#some code
cat('OK \n')
test()
cat('After error \n')
```

[image]

With `recover`:
[image]

And to get back to default:

```
options(error=NULL)
```

Comment: I'm familiar with `options=recover`. What's the difference?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thanks for your question : `recover` is an even better option because it allows to open the function causing the error and places the cursor at the error's location, which seems very near to OP's question. `browser` just opens a browser and tells where the error occured, without opening the function. If you don't mind I'm going to illustrate both behaviours, or you could just post another answer.

Comment: sure, go ahead!

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thanks for your feedback, done.

Comment: One thing to mention:  if you save the file and "source" it (e.g. by clicking on Source in the source pane) you get better results than if you just execute it a line at a time, because you won't get the message "Debug location is approximate because the source is not available".  This also works if the function definition is sourced from one file, and the line is executed from another.

Comment: @user2554330 , you're absolutely right, and this wasn't the case in the example I published because I didn't save+source the code of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried R Studio? It has "Debug" tool
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843?version=1.3.1093&mode=desktop
Also in console you can see the warning with the wrong line. Sorry if I did not understand your question.

Comment: Indeed, console does give the error line, but I want Source to move automatically to the error line with my cursor. You think that's possible? I hope my question is clear. I am not referring to any code, just to SHIFT+ALT+XXXX keyboard shortcuts. Thanks for helping me out!